# Use VBA to find name of linked Excel chart object in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Suppose I copy an Excel chart and then in PowerPoint I do `Paste Special > Keep Source Formatting and Link Data`. This will create a `Shape` object whose `.Chart.ChartData.IsLinked` property is True. What I am trying to figure out is how I can use VBA inside of PowerPoint to determine what Excel chart object is being linked to. For example, consider the code below:

```
Private Sub PrintLinks()
    Dim pptPresentation As Presentation
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptShape As Shape
    
    Set pptPresentation = ActivePresentation
    For Each pptSlide In pptPresentation.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShape.Type = msoChart Then
                Debug.Print pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                Debug.Print pptShape.Chart.Name
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The `.LinkFormat.SourceFullName` property points to the name of the Excel file, but does not indicate the name of the chart object within the file that is being linked to. Likewise, the `.Chart.Name` property does print a name like `Chart 1`, but I've found that this does not correspond to the name of the chart within Excel itself, i.e. when you click on the chart in Excel and look at the object name in the upper left next to the formula bar it can be something different.

Comment: If you don't find it in the `pptShape` properties you might find it somwhere in the xml content of the saved PPT file (if you unzip it and look at the component xml files)

Comment: >> If pptShape.Type = msoChart Then  ... you want to be looking for shapes of type msoLinkedOLEObject (=10)

Comment: Doing the Paste Special approach I mention though yields data that is linked to the Excel file but not a shape of type msoLinkedOLEObject. I would get an msoLinkedOLEObject if doing Paste Link, but I explicitly what to do Link Data, which is different (the resulting object's visual formatting is different)

Comment: @Abiel OK. But last I checked, a Chart object in PowerPoint will tell you whether its data is linked or not, but doesn't tell you what file it's linked TO.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg It does indeed tell me if it is linked, and actually I can get the file it is linked to via the `.LinkFormat.SourceFullName` property, as shown above. But I can't figure out the final step and determine what chart object within the Excel file is being linked to.

Comment: What does .SourceFullName return when you query it?

Comment: It will return the name of the Excel file that the chart is linked to, like `C:/chartifle.xlsx`. If it were msoLinkedOLEObject then it would be something like `C:/chartifle.xlsx!Chart 1`

Comment: That's good news; I've complained to MS for years because at one time, and for several versions, you definitely got nothing when you queried .SourceFullName.  Thanks for that.